# select parent given child id

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

A seemingly simple problem turns out more difficult than I thought:

```
public class SomeCategory 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SomeClass> SomeInstances { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

There is a 1:m relationship between SomeClass and SomeCategory (i.e. an instance of SomeClass belongs to exactly one SomeCategory and SomeCategory can have several SomeClass instances).

Question how do I get the SomeCategory given a SomeClass Id (Linq to NHibernate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you will have access to `SomeCategory` list, then try

```
var category = someCategoryList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.SomeInstances
                               .Any(a => a.Id == someclassId));
```

Comment: I think this will also work 
            var test = (from c in session.Query<Category>()
                        from c1 in t.Classes
                        where c1.Id == id
                        select c).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using QueryOver.

```
Parent parentAlias = null;
Child childAlias = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<Parent>(() => parentAlias)
                   .JoinAlias(()=> parent.Childs, ()=> childAlias)
                   .Where(()=> childAlias.Parent.Id == id)
                   .Select(()=> childAlias.Parent)
                   .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Completely offtopic, can someone explain why NH has an API that looks like that? why argless lambdas?

Comment: The QueryOver API is the strongly-typed version of ICriteria's API. The argless lambdas act just like an alias in the SQL. Also, it helps you to construct queries without the need of forcedly refer to the QueryOver<Parent> class. I really prefer the QueryOver over LINQ queries. It's much more readable even when building dynamic queries. :)